# CPU no pipeline vs 1 stage pipeline

Tags: cpu, architecture

I was taking the the P.E. practice exam and there is a question that shows a CPU without pipeline stages.  There were options for both a 1 stage pipeline or that it was a non-pipelined architecture.  The correct answer was that it was non-pipelined.

What is the difference between a non-pipelined architecture and a 1 stage pipeline architecture?  I had assumed that they were the same thing.

Comment: Why would you assume that? It either has a pipeline or it doesn't.

Comment: @Finbarr I'd argue with Eric: what's a one-stage pipeline if not simply a single-issue CPU?

Comment: If Eris and Marcus are right (it's what I thought, too) then I think it's clear to me the right answer is non-pipelined. Nobody in their right mind would call a non-pipelined architecture a 1-stage pipeline in real life.

Comment: (I guess a 0 stage pipeline meant asynchronous.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what would 1-pipelined CPU architecture look like, but the following can be a valid definition for N-stage pipelined circuit

> An acyclic circuit with N registers for every path from input to output

So, a combinational circuit can be defined as 0-stage pipelined or non-pipelined circuit.

While the following acyclic circuit is a 1-stage pipelined circuit
[image]

You can tell that chaining the output of `B` to another combinational logic would just increase the propagation delay as they now act as a 1 big acyclic circuit.

Another pipeline register can be added to the above circuit output to avoid such issue making it a 2-stage pipelined circuit [image]

Answer (score 0):

Almost all CPU cores in the market today are designed with multiple pipeline stages (greater than 1); see a classic CPU example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_RISC_pipeline). A 1 stage pipeline simply implies that all major stages of a typical CPU, such as fetch, decode, execute, memory and write back are all done in one cycle a.k.a, the CPU core itself is not pipelined (a non-pipelined architecture).

Comment: Not necessarily; I believe it would count as non-pipelined if it did all those stages in multiple cycles, as long as it didn't fetch the next instruction before it finished writeback of the current instruction.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if a non-pipelined design is practical (possible) for an entire CPU. But it sure is possible for shorter sections of logic.

A non-pipelined logic section produces the output state in the same clock cycle the inputs are applied. Since an exam sheet probably is constrained to display small sections of logic, this can surely happen.

A pipelined logic chain, in contrast, contains memory, e.g. edge-triggered D-Flipflops. During each clock cycle, the signal flows only from one memory to the next, instead of all the way from input to output.